# Django redirect still shows Form View on redirect

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm currently implementing a pretty standard class-based FormView and on form_valid I want to redirect to another view (not class-based). However, the URL redirect happens ok, but the template shown still reflects the form view from before.

```
class EmailView(FormView):
    template_name = 'landing/index.html'
    form_class = EmailForm
    success_url = 'success'

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = form.cleaned_data['email']
            e = Email(email_address=address.lower())

            return redirect('success')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'landing/thank-you.html')
```

And yes, I've correctly mapped 'success' to my success view in URLConf. Any ideas?

Comment: You're saying the URL loads to the new view, but the template is not the `thank-you` template? That's a very unlikely critical bug.

Can you describe your URLConf for these 2 views, as well as demonstrate the URL redirected to in the browser (aka what `redirect('success')` resolves to, and finally if the `success` function is actually firing (print statements, log, etc.)

Comment: from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from landing import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', views.EmailView.as_view(), name='landing'),
    url(r'^thank-you/$', views.success, name='success'),
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a URL that matches everything and is matching before your `thank-you` page.

You need to add a `$` after your `^` to make sure that URL only matches exactly one pattern, and not basically everything.

```
url(r'^$', views.EmailView.as_view(), name='landing'),
#      ^ this must be added
url(r'^thank-you/$', views.success, name='success') #......
```